# Pytest mark parametrize with multiple choice

Tags: python, pytest

I worked with Pytest and everything works fine with the example below:

```
import pytest

class params:
    gpu = -1

test_params = {
    # param0,
    "gpu": (-1, params.gpu),
    # param2,
    # param3,
    # param4,
    # param5,
}

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "line, expected",
    test_params.values(),
    ids=list(test_params.keys()),
)
def test_map(line, expected):
    print(line)
    assert line == expected
```

I tried to add `"gpu": ([-1, 1], params.gpu)`, in order to have the choice between **-1** or **1** as acceptable value in case I want to set `gpu = 1` in the class params but the test failed. Any suggestions to include this choice?

Comment: `assert expected in line` if `line` is a list of valid values?

Comment: Yes. The idea is to be able to validate several values with the same test. ```"gpu"``` can have as value ```= 1``` or ```= 0``` or ```= -1```.
In order to optimize the tests, I don't want to create several tests, but only one that can be flexible.

Comment: What is the code under test? What are you actually trying to verify in the test?

Comment: I try to check if the user has input the right values as arguments.
The test works on a single scenario where we get the arguments from a YAML file. However, if the user only wants to change the value chosen for the GPU, how could we validate the test with a flexibility of choosing the GPU value?

Comment: ```class params:  gpu = -1``` 
is only to illustrate an example.
Realistically, we parse the values from a line command.

Comment: If the yaml file is supplied by a user at run time, it's not part of your code, so shouldn't you have a function for loading and validating the config file and this function should be tested instead?

Comment: An example quite close to what I want to do :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45577613/use-pytest-to-test-multiple-options